# SHA256 image hash is not same in Dart(flutter) vs node js(firebase functions)

Tags: node.js, flutter, dart, google-cloud-functions, sha256

I'm newbie to node js , I am using node version **v10.21.0** with firebase functions, flutter **1.20.3** (dart **2.9.2**)

I am generating the SHA256 hash for the image file in dart then , uploading the a zipped image files into the storage. Dart code is as below for generating image hash:

```
Future<String> generateImageHash(File file) async {
  var image_bytes = file.readAsBytesSync().toString();
  var bytes = utf8.encode(image_bytes); // data being hashed
  String digest = sha256.convert(bytes).toString();
  return digest;
}
```

When downloading the zipped file from cloud storage using **firebase** functions I am unzipping the file , storing them in temp directory and then generating the SHA256 hash for the image files as shown below :

```
fs.readFile(path.join(dir, file), (err, fd) => {
if (!err) {
     crypto.createHash('sha256').update(fd).digest('hex');
   }
}
```

However the **SHA256** hash is not same as that generated from dart code.However if I download the zip file from cloud storage in **dart** code and generate the hash for the files it matches the **SHA256** hash generated before uploading

What could be the issue ? I have tried with previous **SO** posts with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the issue is in my dart code not in the node js as I was thinking
This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57385832/flutter-compute-function-for-image-hashing/62202544#62202544) helped